# My touchpad isn't responding

Tags: touchpad, ubuntu-gnome

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 before this I had windows 10 installed and the touchpad was working fine but since I installed Ubuntu 18.04 the touchpad isn't working.

So far, I have tried to install `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`, then I also tried going into `/etc/default/grub` and to edit the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

and replace `quiet splash` to `acpi=force`. But that also didn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

A few hardware details would be welcome to find out what's going wrong.
Could you complete your answer with the output of `sudo dmidecode -s system-product-name` (so we get your computer model) and `egrep -i 'synap|alps|etps' /proc/bus/input/devices` (to try to find out more information about your touchpad).

Be sure to check out *System Settings > Devices > Mouse & Touchpad* as well as *Software & Updates > Additional Drivers* to see if your touchpad appears there.

EDIT: If you don't have an additional mouse, it of course won't help (you can still do the terminal part from the terminal or tty's). Assuming your touchpad is managed by Synaptics (and doesn't show in /proc/bus/input/devices), try purging synaptics and installing it again:
    sudo apt-get purge synaptics-touchpad
    sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-synaptics

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall xserver-xorg-input-synaptics and install xserver-xorg-input-libinput.

`sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-libinput`

After installation, reboot.

Once you login, open GNOME Tweaks. If you do not have it installed, you can run

`sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`

or use the Software Center.

Go to `Keyboard & Mouse` and click it. Look for an option that says TouchPad. Toggle `Disable While Typing` to OFF.

Then open Settings (top-right drop-down menu, far left icon depicting a spanner and screwdriver in the shape of an x).

Go to `Devices` and click on it. Then select `Mouse & Touchpad`.
Under the option Touchpad toggle `Touchpad` to ON.